# Convert const char* to UTF16 from C on macOS and Windows?

Tags: c, character-encoding, wchar-t, wchar, multibyte-characters

My attempts seem hacky and overly convoluted. Is there a simple way to convert ASCII to UTF16 on Windows and macOS?

(note that the `prUTF16Char` I can't change )

#### Attempt (written via https://stackoverflow.com/a/54376330)

##### Prelude

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#if defined(__APPLE__) && defined(__MACH__)
#include <xcselect.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
typedef unsigned short int prUTF16Char;
#else
typedef wchar_t prUTF16Char;
#endif

#define WIDEN2(x) L ## x
#define WIDEN(x) WIDEN2(x)
#define PROJECT_NAME "foo"
```

#### Functions

```c
void copy2ConvertStringLiteralIntoUTF16(const wchar_t* inputString, prUTF16Char* destination) {
    size_t length = wcslen(inputString);
#if (defined(_WIN32) || defined(__WIN32__) || defined(__WINDOWS__)) && defined(PLUGIN_MODE)
    wcscpy_s(destination, length + 1, inputString);
#elif defined(__APPLE__) && defined(__MACH__)
    CFRange range = {0, 150}; range.length = length;
    CFStringRef inputStringCFSR = CFStringCreateWithBytes(
        kCFAllocatorDefault, reinterpret_cast<const UInt8 *>(inputString),
        length * sizeof(wchar_t), kCFStringEncodingUTF32LE, false);
    CFStringGetBytes( inputStringCFSR, range, kCFStringEncodingUTF16, 0, false,
                      reiterpret_cast<UInt8 *>(destination), length * (sizeof (prUTF16Char)), NULL);
    destination[length] = 0; // Set NULL-terminator
    CFRelease(inputStringCFSR);
#endif
}

const prUTF16Char * to_wchar(const char* message) {
    const size_t cSize = strlen(message);
    wchar_t *w_str = new wchar_t[cSize];
#if defined(_WIN32) || defined(__WIN32__) || defined(__WINDOWS__)
    size_t outSize;
    mbstowcs_s(&outSize, w_str, cSize, message, cSize-1);
    return w_str;
#else
    mbstowcs(w_str, message, cSize);
#endif
#if defined(__APPLE__) && defined(__MACH__)
    prUTF16Char *ut16str = new prUTF16Char[cSize];
    copy2ConvertStringLiteralIntoUTF16(w_str, ut16str);
    return ut16str;
#else
    return w_str;
#endif
}
```

Then I can just define a global var:

```c
static const prUTF16Char* PROJECT_NAME_W =
#if defined(__APPLE__) && defined(__MACH__)
    to_wchar
#elif defined(_WIN32) || defined(__WIN32__) || defined(__WINDOWS__)
    WIDEN
#endif
        (PROJECT_NAME);
```

And the body of a generic print function taking `message`:

```c
#if WCHAR_UTF16
wprintf(L"%s",
#else
    printf("%ls\n",
#endif
    message);
```

Full attempt:

https://github.com/SamuelMarks/premiere-pro-cmake-plugin/blob/f0d2278/src/common/logger.cpp [rewriting from C++ to C]

Error:

**error: initializer element is not a compile-time constant**

---

EDIT: Super hacky, but with @barmak-shemirani's solution I can:

```c
#if defined(__APPLE__) && defined(__MACH__)
extern
#elif defined(_WIN32) || defined(__WIN32__) || defined(__WINDOWS__)
static
#endif
const prUTF16Char* PROJECT_NAME_W
#if defined(__APPLE__) && defined(__MACH__)
    ;
#elif defined(_WIN32) || defined(__WIN32__) || defined(__WINDOWS__)
    WIDEN(PROJECT_NAME);
#endif
```

…and only initialise and `free` on the `extern` variant.

Comment: This is tagged as C but includes `new`, did you just forget to replace it?

Comment: "Convert ASCII to [Unicode]" is confused; ASCII is already a subset of Unicode. Can you please [edit] to explain in more detail what the code should do? Trivially, a pure-ASCII string `"hello"` corresponds to `"h\x00e\x00l\x00l\x00o\x00"` in UTF-16 (though the null bytes will obviously be problematic in regular C strings ... one of the many reasons to prefer https://utf8everywhere.org/)

Comment: @BarmakShemirani - Yeah that and the casts I was still converting from C++ when I realised that this all seemed wayyyy too convoluted. @tripleee Also I'm working in C90 so I can't actually use UTF8 everywhere… not to mention that I'm conforming to someone else's API [Adobe's] and need to accept regular `const char*` input in some places (that I need to convert to the unicode variant used by the API)

Answer (score 1):

`message` includes the null terminating character. `strlen` does not count this last character, `cSize` has to increase by `1`.

Usually you need to call [setlocal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte/mbstowcs) if for example `message` was typed in non-English computer. But it's okay if `message` is guaranteed to be ASCII.

Windows Example:

```
const wchar_t* to_wchar(const char* message) 
{ 
    const size_t cSize = strlen(message) + 1;
    //wchar_t* w_str = new wchar_t[cSize]; using C++?
    wchar_t* w_str = malloc(cSize * sizeof(wchar_t));

    size_t outSize;
    mbstowcs(w_str, message, cSize);
    // or mbstowcs_s(&outSize, w_str, cSize, message, cSize);

    return w_str;
}
```

Note that `wchar_t` is 2 bytes in Windows, and 4 bytes in POSIX. Then UTF-16 has 2 different version, little-endian and big-endian. UTF-16 has 2-bytes per character for ASCII equivalent codes, but 4-bytes for some non-Latin languages.

You should consider UTF-8 output. Most Windows programs are prepared to read UTF-8 from file or network.

Windows byte output for `"123"`:

```
49 00 50 00 51 00 00 00 <- little-endian
0  49 00 50 00 51 00 00 <- big-endian
```

Linux byte output from above code (this won't be recognized as UTF-16 by Winodws):

```
49 00 00 00 50 00 00 00 51 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

---

You can write your own function if you are 100% certain that the message is ASCII

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
 
typedef unsigned short prUTF16Char;//remove this line later

prUTF16Char* to_wchar(const char* message)
{
    if (!message) return NULL;

    size_t len = strlen(message);
    int bufsize = (len + 1) * 2;
    char* buf = malloc(bufsize);

    int little_endian = 1;
    little_endian = ((char*)&little_endian)[0];
    memset(buf, 0, bufsize);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
        buf[i * 2 + little_endian ? 0 : 1] = message[i];

    return (prUTF16Char*)buf;
}

prUTF16Char* wstr;
int main()
{
    wstr = to_wchar("ASCII");
    wprintf(L"%s\n", wstr);
    free(wstr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Aside: Consider `w_str = malloc(cSize * sizeof(wchar_t));` --> `w_str = malloc(sizeof *w_str * cSize);`.  Easier to code right, review and maintain.

Comment: Thanks, good catch (the off by 1 error). Hmm, wasn't aware of the whole endianness issue for string encoding… but yeah I do need UTF16 because of the really old API I need to conform to (Adobe's, which has the aforementioned `typedef` for UTF16). In terms of the provided solution, I believe that won't resolve the assignment to my global. Does that mean I have to make my global non-static, or is there another way?

Comment: I don't know what you mean about global non-static. You can assume Windows is little-endian (anything on x86/x64, specially old programs). The problem I mention is when you use `mbstowcs` on different systems, the output string could be wrong, otherwise C compiler doesn't care about this.

Comment: Also I am confused now how your program works. It's fine if your program is running on Windows and talking to another Window application.

Comment: `static const prUTF16Char* PROJECT_NAME_W = to_wchar(PROJECT_NAME);` is what I mean by the global static. (something which doesn't need to be `free`d by me). My project has two modes, 'plugin' and 'standalone'. 'plugin' requires the Adobe SDK and does things like output to the Adobe console. 'standalone' can work without Adobe's SDK—or even C++—and the example code is the API I'm trying to get working. `log_info(message)` should output `message` using stdout on 'standalone' and Adobe-specific API on 'plugin'. (this was working in C++; I'm rewriting in C)

Comment: global variables are already persistent, it doesn't need `static`. You don't need constant here, note this is a pointer being allocated. You can add static const if you want. See the example shown for conversion without dependency on Windows.

Comment: Also note, in Windows you can use code pages to write Greek using `char`. That won't be ASCII. It's unlikely that Adobe decided to use UTF16 for no reason.

Comment: Thanks that is certainly useful. I've edited my question to include how I would handle a global with your setup.