# Check platform and use the correct printf form

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, console-application

It's been 10 years since I've learned C++ during high school, now I'm playing around it again and I'll already facing some problems regarding multi-platform.

I saw that if I want to display special characters on windows, I should use wprintf. However, on *nix systems, it is not necessary.

So, how can I detect what is the current platform, so I can run printf or wprintf depending on it?

### UPDATE

I'll open a new question with the error and close this one.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use `wprintf` (or `wcout <<`) on either platform.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130407/c-wide-characters-outputting-incorrectly) for an example.